# ES6 Re-packing properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
this.state = {
  tabs: props.tabs,
  activeTabs: props.tabs.map( tab => {
    return {
      linksTo: tab.linksTo,
      icon: tab.icon,
      name: tab.name,
      selected: tab.selected || false,
      clicked: a=>{ props.onTabClick(tab) }
    }
  })
}
```

Is there any ES6 shorthand to avoid re-typing property names e.g. "linksTo" while keeping the function body limited to just the return statement? I apologize if this is a duplicate, I ask this after at least a week of low-intensity googling.

**E** Fixed by adding this to my webpack config:

```
      plugins: [
        'transform-es2015-destructuring',
        'transform-es2015-parameters',
        'transform-object-rest-spread'
      ]
```

Comment: does `tab` contain only `linksTo`, `icon`, `name`, `selected` property or some more also?

Comment: Only those properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `tab` is an object so you can directly return that with one extra key `onClick`.

Either use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
this.state = {
  tabs: props.tabs,
  activeTabs: props.tabs.map( tab => ({
      clicked: a => props.onTabClick(tab),
      ...tab
  }))
}
```

Or use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
this.state = {
  tabs: props.tabs,
  activeTabs: props.tabs.map( tab => Object.assign(
      {},
      clicked: a => props.onTabClick(tab),
      tab
  ))
}
```

Comment: Giving this a shot, it's looking very close to what we need.

Comment: I'm looking at the first solution, since it's the most condensed one, and it pleases the pre-optimizer in me, but I'm getting an Unexpected Token syntax error on the spread operator `...tab`. Any ideas?

Comment: that's why is suggested the 2nd one, because object spread is not yet included in es (array spread has been included), you need to use babel plugin, use this: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/ :)

Comment: google this you will find many solutions: **object spread throwing error in react**, check [**mdn doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) statement: "The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 4) adds spread properties to object literals."

Comment: Thank you!!! I was tearing hair trying to figure out why this seemingly standard feature wasn't working. Accepting.